# ssh tail with nested ls and head cannot access

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

am trying to execute the following command:

```
$ ssh root@10.10.10.50 "tail -F -n 1  $(ls -t /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log | head -n1 )"

ls: cannot access /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log: No such file or directory
tail: cannot follow `-' by name
```

notice the error returned, when i login to ssh separately and then execute

```
tail -F -n 1  $(ls -t /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log | head -n1 )"
```

see the below:

```
# ls -t /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log | head -n1 
/var/log/alert_ARCDB.log
```

why is that happening and how to fix it. am trying to do this in one line as i don't want to create a script file.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Shell parameter expansion happens *before* command execution.

Here's a simple example.  If I type...

```
ls "$HOME"
```

...the shell replaces `$HOME` with the path to my home directory first, then runs something like `ls /home/larsks`.  The `ls` command has no idea that the command line originally had `$HOME`.

If we look at your command...

```
$ ssh root@10.10.10.50 "tail -F -n 1  $(ls -t /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log | head -n1 )"
```

...we see that you're in exactly the same situation.  The `$(ls -t ...)` expression is expanded *before* `ssh` is executed.  In other words, that command is running your *local* system.

You can inhibit the shell expansion on your local system by using single quotes.  For example, running:

```
echo '$HOME'
```

Will produce:

```
$HOME
```

So you can run:

```
ssh root@10.10.10.50 'tail -F -n 1  $(ls -t /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log | head -n1 )'
```

But there's another problem here.  If `/var/log/alert_ARCDB.log` is a *file*, your command makes no sense: calling `ls -t` on a single file gets you nothing.

If `alert-ARCDB.log` is a *directory*, you have a different problem.  The result of `ls /some/directory` is a list of filenames without any directory prefix.  If I run something like:

```
ls -t /tmp
```

I will get output like

```
file1
file2
```

If I do this:

```
tail $(ls -t /tmp | head -1)
```

I end up with a command that looks like:

```
tail file1
```

And that will fail, because there is no `file1` in my *current* directory.

Comment: thanks for your explanation that really make sense now to me, however the log file exists in a remote server. so i did the below and it works ssh root@10.10.10.50 tail -F -n 1 $(ssh root@10.10.10.50 ls -t /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log | head -n1) but am doing ssh twice is there any way i can do this in one ssh call

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to pipe the commands you want to perform to ssh.  One simple way to achieve that is to first create a function that will echo the commands you want executed :

```
remote_commands()
{
  echo 'cd /var/log/alert_ARCDB.log'
  echo 'tail -F -n 1  "$(ls -t | head -n1 )"'
}
```

The `cd` will allow you to use the relative path listed by `ls`.  The single quotes make sure that everything will be sent as-is to the remote shell, with no local expansion occurring.

Then you can do

```
ssh root@10.10.10.50 bash < <(remote_commands)
```

This assumes `alert_ARCDB.log` is a directory (or else I am not sure why you would want to add `head -n1` after that).